# How to deal with proxy servers that block specific HTTP request methods?

Tags: api, rest, http, proxy

I'm designing a REST web API, but noticed something weird lately.

Apparently some proxy servers are blocking specific HTTP request methods. In my case the PUT and PATCH methods which are crucial to modify resources. This partially breaks the functionality of the API I'm designing...

Is there a good way to bypass this problem without breaking the RESTful architecture constraints? In my opinion there isn't, because fully using the HTTP verbs is advocated when designing a REST web API over HTTP...

Comment: Whose proxies are that? Who will be using your API?

Comment: Apparently our internal enterprise proxy server is blocking PUT and PATCH methods... doesn't make sense to me, but it's just like that. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Ignore it. People who willingly break the(ir) web (experience) using a malconfigured proxy server will have to deal with the consequences themselves.
- Ask the proxy administrators to whitelist your host or the methods it accepts.
- Rewrite your API, "breaking" REST principles.
- Use HTTPS, so the proxy will only see the connect method.

Comment: I was thinking about just ignoring it, yes. And your last remark is completely making me sure about going in that direction. Currently the API is still in development and we're using HTTP, but once it goes in production we're going to use HTTPS anyway, so when the proxy only "sees" the CONNECT method, I guess the problem will solve itself... Thanks for the tips! :-)

Comment: It looks like we got the same problem (a client for which everything works fine at home but PATCH request fails at its office), even though our app & API are available in HTTPS only...

Comment: @Maxime it's nasty, but the client could use a trusted root certificate to actually generate certificates on the fly and decrypt all HTTPS traffic.

Comment: @CodeCaster Knowing the type of office he is in, I wouldn't be surprised... I'm torn between change the whole architecture of my API and saying to this client to change its broken network....

Comment: @Maxime or offer to set up a VPN.